# How to use Vector with offset from parent Haxe class instance?

Tags: arrays, haxe

What methods are available to achieve accessing parent instance Vector cell from another class?

My question is about the lines commented with "??":

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var a:A = new A();
        var b:B = new B(a, 115);
    }
}

class A {
    public var cells:haxe.ds.Vector<Float>;

    public function new() {
        cells = new haxe.ds.Vector(1000);
    }
}

class B {
    public var a:A; // the "parent"
    public var my_offset:Int;
    public var my_cells:haxe.ds.Vector<Float>; //??

    public function new(a:A, offset:Int) {
        my_offset = offset;
        my_cells[2] = 0.5; //?? actually a.cells[my_offset + 2];
    }

}
```

Is it possible to:

- access parent Vector memory directly?
- use a macro?
- use an abstract?

*["Try Haxe" link](https://try.haxe.org/#7E879)*

Comment: Just stumbled over this old question again. Did my answer answer it, or was there still something unclear? :)

Answer (score 3):

You could create an `abstract` type that wraps a `Vector`, automatically adding the desired offset by defining [`@:arrayAccess()` methods](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-array-access.html):

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        var cells = new haxe.ds.Vector(1000);
        cells[115] = 1.5;

        var cellsWithOffset = new VectorWithOffset(cells, 115);
        trace(cellsWithOffset[0]); // 1.5
    }
}

abstract VectorWithOffset<T>(VectorWithOffsetData<T>) {
    public function new(vector:haxe.ds.Vector<T>, offset:Int) {
        this = {vector: vector, offset: offset};
    }

    @:arrayAccess inline function get(i:Int):T {
        return this.vector[i + this.offset];
    }

    @:arrayAccess inline function set(i:Int, v:T):T {
        return this.vector[i + this.offset] = v;
    }
}

typedef VectorWithOffsetData<T> = {
    var vector:haxe.ds.Vector<T>;
    var offset:Int;
}
```

**Note:** the abstract doesn't need to necessarily wrap a structure, it could also be a class. You can't wrap `Vector` directly though, as the `offset` needs to be stored somewhere, and abstracts can't have member variables of their own.